# Can javascript access/modify browser certification authorities?

Tags: javascript, security, certificate, ca

I'm trying to up my level in javascript security so I was wondering if there is an api the would allow some javascript to add/change/delete the list of authorities ?
I've read a little bit about the notification part for example and I discovered some security aspect I hadn't a clue about it ... (but this is another thing).

Any idea ? thanks

Edit: I don't think the question is too broad, noob for sure... To make it clearer, I can change cookies using javascript , can I change what's in settings => advanced => https/ssl => manage certificate (in chrome for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way for Javascript in a page to do that.

It may be possible to do that in a browser plugin, but I guess that's not what you are asking for.

Comment: Clear answer thanks. To make the question a little bit broader , do you have  some hints about where to look to know what's the border of what javascript can have a grip on within the browser ? (obviously certificates would be a security issue, but I believe bad plugins too , really a plugin can ***** up your certificates O_o ? what I mean by certificates is authorities list here

Comment: @FrançoisRichard: JavaScript doesn't have that level of control. Mainly it is just limited to controlling the DOM. Plugins have more power, however to do anything such as modifying root certificates would require a native component with administrator level privileges.